# Search a text in selected coding system in file hierarchy

Tags: emacs, internationalization, full-text-search, grep, posix

I want to search for text in a specified coding system (cp1251/UTF-8/UTF-16-le/iso-8859-4, etc) in a file hierarchy.

For example I have source code in **cp1251** coding and I run Debian with system coding **UTF-8**. **grep** or Midnight Commander perform searches in UTF-8 coding. So I can not find Russian words.

Preferred solutions will use standard POSIX or GNU command line utilities (like **grep**).

MC or Emacs solution also appreciated.

I tried:

```
$ grep `echo Привет | iconv -f cp1251 -t utf-8` *
```

but this command does not show results sometimes.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. Could you please describe what happens with that command and what you would like to happen.

Comment: For example I have source code in **cp1251** coding and I run Debian with system coding **UTF-8**. When I perform search in Midnight Commander it uses system coding only...

Answer (score 2):

The command you proposed outputs the string Привет, then pipes the result of that output to iconv and applies grep to the result of iconv. That is not what you want. What you want is this:

```
find . -type f -printf "iconv -f cp1251 -t utf-8 '%p' | grep --label '%p' -H 'Привет'\n" | sh
```

This applies iconv, followed by grep, to every file below the current directory.

But note that this assumes that **all** of your files are in CP1251. It will fail if only *some* of them are. In that case you'd first have to write a program that *detects* the encoding of a file and then applies iconv only if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line:

```
LANG=ru_RU.cp1251 grep Привет *
```

Comment: This not work. If teminal configured to use **UTF-8** it pass "Привет" as **UTF-8** and grep does not perform recoding search pattern to **cp1251**. so instead of searching in cp1251 grep perfrm search in UTF-8.